# How can I r/w cv::Mat row by row

Tags: c++, opencv

I am tring to build some plugin for a software, it's API logic is row based. So in order to use some OpenCV function I need to fill this row based data into cv::Mat and read from it in a loop through all rows.
I don't know how can I do this. If RGB can be seperatly handled would be better.
The language I'm using is C++.

Comment: Which language you are using, please try to be more clear in your question

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html

Comment: Hi Temurlenk. I forgot OpenCV supports multiple language, It's C++.

Comment: Hi beaker, there are some point may help, but it's quiet late here. I'll dig deeper tomorrow. Thanks for the doc.